# Need suggestion the execute multiple directory scans

Tags: php, ajax

I need some backup because I am running out of ideas how I should solve this "problem". I don't want you to write any code for me. But If you have an idea how I should do this please let me know:

**The basic function:** Im writing am Programm which scans a directory and lists this in HTML (read directory: scandir()[PHP] -> Output to HTML). So far not that hard and everything works fine. I am scanning the directory while generating the page, so at first call of the file. After this everything is static again.

**Purpose:** Now I want to navigate through the directories. I'm already able to do this, but everytime I am about to change the directory, I need to reload the page (Sent HTTP-Header to itself). This works.. but I really don't like it. You might understand me. So I want to find a way how a can perform multiple times a scan of the directory without realoading the page. Maybe anyone of you already faced something similar and has some tipps for me?

So what my code looks like now (Superficially):

```
// Header and stuff
$dir_scan = 'a directory'; <-Reperform the whole function--
                                                           |
$elements = dirscan($dir_scan , 1);                        |
                                                           |
for($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++)                   |
{                                                          |
    // show elements via Index: $elements[$i];             |
                                                           |
    ////////////////Element_1/////////////////             |
    ////////////////Element_2///////////////// -> onclick -
    etc.
}

// Footer and stuff
```

Comment: How about some nice Ajax magic ?

Comment: The Problem is: I tried Ajax but because i built the DOM generic by loading the page, I would need to return most of the tags to the master. And even If I got them how should i output them the from JS/JQ to php..

Comment: Or I guess I am just performing the AJAX-Call the wrong way

Comment: I don't understand why the page reloads. You hit a .php and that php just scans for directories right? Oh, you do that through a click. You could use an ajax call then - OR - by the time you hit the .php scan all files and play with jQuery to show/hide each directory element.

Comment: Yes now basically this directory gets displayed, everything fine. Now because I am building the DOM via PHP there no other way for me the call this scan-function by a html-event (onclick) than reload the page and give the function a new value (received over POST-HTTP-Header). You know what I mean? @AntonisTsimourtos

Comment: See updated comment. I believe it is better to load them all together and just hide them. Then, onclick show specific element scans.

Comment: So you suggesst me to preload around 100 directories containing around 5k files?